# Google Play Console: Lost the upload key which is required to upload the APK

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-signing

I have lost my **upload key** which is required to upload the android APK file on Google Play Console. Tried with a new key but since the fingerprints don't match it doesn't work.

However, I have 'App Signing' by Google enabled. So, I'm hoping to not unpublish the app and do the entire "Create Application" process on Google Play Console.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you’ve lost your private upload key, or it’s been compromised, you can [create a new](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423#create) one, and then ask your account [owner to contact support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs) to reset the key. When contacting support, make sure your account owner attaches the upload_certificate.pem file.

After our support team registers the new upload key, you receive an email, and then you can update your keystores and register your key with API providers.

Important: Resetting your upload key doesn’t affect the app signing key that Google Play uses to re-sign APKs before delivering them to users.