# Can I uninstall my app which is in beta release of play store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, beta

I have my game on play store which is in beta release. And I have lost password of key to update my game.
Can I remove my beta version game and upload new production release (Android app bundle) file with different key password

Comment: You can unpublish it but not remove it, and upload a new bundle with different package name to production. Or try to remember the password.

Answer (score 0):

A production release is still an update and needs to be signed with the same upload key. If you opted into Google Play Signing, which you can check in App Integrity for the menu for the app in Play Console. If that is the case you can follow these instructions to reset it [Reset Upload Key SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58342610/11208036) or contact support here [Google Play Support - Reset Instructions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?_ga=2.3157616.1780063887.1634191291-404034739.1633768783#reset). If you didnt use play signing. You have to publish under a different package name.